# Regex to replace [something]KeepThisPart

Tags: php, regex

I need some regex to strip the `[` and `]` off the start of the string, and anything in the middle, so:

`[text]KeepThis` should be `KeepThis`.

I can't seem to get my head around how to do it (far to long since I used regex :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace( '/^\[.*?\]/', '', $string );
```

The regex finds any pair of brackets and their content from the beginning of the string and replaces it with an empty string.

Comment: What would it do to this string `[[[text]foo[bar]]flam]Keep this` ?

Comment: @sln: `foo[bar]]flam]Keep this`. @OP: Please supply examples of the correct interpretation if you are expecting strings like this one.

Comment: @webnoob - worked like a charm but did you get your head around the regular expression?

Comment: @sln - Yes I did thanks, it's not that far off from what I was trying. I just didn't have the ^ or the ? in there.